# BigQuery - day of week number where Monday = 1

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a standard way to return "day of week number" (1-7) in ISO standard (Monday = 1) from a date in BigQuery using built in functions?

`EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK, <date>)` returns a number using US format i.e. Sunday = 1, which doesn't work for my purpose.

I can create a custom function to calculate the ISO day of week number but I'm not sure whether I'm missing something built in that I can use instead.

Comment: no, you are not missing anything  - just go with custom function and optionally submit feature request

Comment: Thanks - do you know where I should submit such a request for BigQuery?

Comment: You can submit feature request at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) . Also consider voting up answer if it was helpful :o)

Comment: Looks like someone (not me) did create an Issue Tracker request for this feature back in April 2021: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185709835 < Go vote on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is example of such function - just one of many options you can come with

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ISODAYOFWEEK(day DATE) AS ((
  SELECT IF(weekday = 0, 7, weekday) 
  FROM UNNEST([EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day) - 1]) weekday 
));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can convert to ISO-standard (Monday = 1) using modulo arithmetic:

```
MOD(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM <date>) + 5, 7) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up defining a custom function for better readability

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION timestampToWeekday(dt timestamp) AS (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM dt)-1 = 0 THEN 7 ELSE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM dt)-1 END);
```

And now I can use this function to convert any timestamp to a weekday.